# left join would return no result when right table not match the left table

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

For example there are two tables: *user* and *comment*

*user*

```
| id              | integer          
| name            | text
```

*comment*

```
| id              | integer
| uid             | integer          
| comment         | text
```

Query:

```
SELECT u.name, c.comment 
FROM   user u LEFT JOIN comment c ON c.uid = u.id 
WHERE  u.id = 1234;
```

If there is no comment match the user, the sql would return no result,
I want one user result(whose id is 1234) even though no comment match  this user, How should I fix the sql?

Comment: does table `user` contains id of `1234`?

Comment: @JW sure, I mean if there are comment match the user, there is no problem.

Comment: i can't see any problem with the code, i have replicated your problem, see this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00476/1

Comment: Also -- are you sure that everything you've posted is correct? Because your query really looks fine. Please run `SELECT name FROM user WHERE id = 1234` and confirm that it does return a row, and then run the *exact* query that you've posted here and confirm that it returns no rows.

Comment: Looks ok to me... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9788/1